# Heroku website shows 'Offline for Maintenance. This app is undergoing maintenance right now. Please check back later'

Tags: heroku, error-handling, offline, maintainability

I have hosted my blog on Heroku through my Github. Even after successfully deploying it, it throws an error as 'Offline for Maintenance. This app is undergoing maintenance right now.  Please check back later'.

Any clue what else should I do?

Answer (score 2):

If https://status.heroku.com shows everything in green, then it is  your app that has gone into maintenance mode. To check the maintenance status, type:

```
heroku maintenance
```

If the result says on, type:

```
heroku maintenance:off
```

To disable the maintenance mode of the app.